# Is there a solution to add dart package in android studio according to my blow errors?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, package

Whenever I install a dart package from https://pub.dev I got an error in my Android Studio terminal like this below:
[image]

I've not only deleted `pubspec.lock` file from my flutter project but also I check the proxy setting but still I got this error.

I am trying to add dart package for my flutter project from https://pub.dev